# Is it possible to view C++ code with instantiated templates before it gets compiled (g++)?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, instantiation, abstract-syntax-tree

the g++ compiler has a flag that produces macro-expanded code (-E), so I am wondering if there is a way to view the program coude after template instantiation before the actual compilation takes place?

Comment: Too bad template instantiation is *part* of the actual compilation process... and not one at the beginning either, it's a step somewhere in the middle. Also, templates are instantiated on demand.

Comment: Comment from the rather silly part of my brain: use "g++ -S" and inspect the generated assembler code!

Comment: @Xeo The fac that they are a part of the compilation process is a problem for sure, but that they are instantiated on demand I don't se as a problem. Why would it (hypothetically) not be possible to output a separate .log file with instantiated templates (for those that are demanded)? Wouldn't this make it a bit easier to debug template codes? Just asking...

Comment: @tomislav - Macro expansion is a pure text replacement, so you can examine the resulting text afterwards. Templates are not, so there is nothing to see, just like you cannot see how `for` or `while` statements are treated by the compiler.

Comment: @BoPerss How are the classes built by the compiler? Can I see anything resembling the c++ syntax and organization of class in the assembly code?

Comment: What information do you hope to glean from seeing this information?

Comment: @tomislav-maric - A compiler generally compiles the source code to some internal format, does some transformations on that and then generates the assembly code. Unless you are extremely familiar with the compiler design, this internal representation isn't readable. And it probably doesn't preserve the class structure anyway.

Comment: @Pete I am just curious if it is possible at all, and how the code looks like. I am a mechanical engineer but I switched to computational science, so I guess I like seeing how things "tick".

Comment: @MatsPetersson, you sure are a masochist, sir.

Comment: @BoPersson, if you compile without optimization it might be possible to follow what is going on in simple cases. If you ask for debugging information, some form of markers indicating source code line numbers and variable definitions are included. But the whole class structure and such is almost completely obliterated.

Comment: There are a bunch of mangled names in the .s file, I'll try to replace them with c++ filt output. :)

Comment: @BoPersson Though the end result of template instantiation (be it even sctattered around the whole compilation process) is nevertheless a replacement of template parameters by actual types (and values), maybe even recursively. For sure these days this isn't done or exported by compilers and is integrated into some totally different internal structuring of the source code during compilation. But nevertheless it *can* be possible (by keeping track of the org. source code), since template instantiation **conceptually** results in mere textual replacement (however complex that replacement may be).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the closer you can get is to read the AST/ABT generated by the compiler:

- AST: Abstract Syntax Tree
- ABT: Abstract Binding Tree

The former represents the view of the syntax as the compiler understands it and the latter is similar *after* resolution of the bindings (ie, that the `a` here is actually the variable that was declared 3 lines before or that the `foo` correspdonds to the function defined in that header...).

Clang allows to dump its AST... which is in fact the ABT, actually, it's being improved at this very moment; sneak developer preview:

```
int Test __attribute__((visibility("default")));

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int x __attribute__((aligned(4))) = 5;
  int y = 2;
  for (;;)
    if (x != y++)
      break;
  return (x * y);
}
```

[image]

Normally you should see how the template was instantiated there.

*Note: to get it you need the `-ast-dump` pass to the clang front-end.*

Comment: The key here, really, is _no_. :)